# Globally set a time constraint for simplifications

Tags: simplifying-expressions, options

I am using a differential geometry package (the now discontinued Atlas) which repeatedly calls the Simplify functions in its computations, which in some cases leads to extremely long (days? In the end I have to abort the computation) evaluation times.

Is there any way to force a maximum time for Simplfy globally? Since the function is called by the package, short of modifying the source code, I cannot pass it as an option.

It's quite likely that expressions are too unwieldy to be of any use but I'd like to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) has the [`TimeConstraint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstraint.html) options, which controls how much it should wait for certain transformations to complete. You can try changing the default value, for example:

```
SetOptions[Simplify, TimeConstraint -> 20]
```

This sets it to be 20 seconds. On startup, the value is 300.

Will this actually help with Atlas? I don't know, but it's worth a try.

It is good to know that some functions will not respect the default option values. I just tested `Simplify` in Mathematica 12.3.1 and I can confirm that it does respect the default `TimeConstraint`.

Comment: It does help with Atlas! I did know about TimeConstraint but thought I could only pass it as an option and not set it globally. Exactly what the answer I needed, thanks!